can excel powerquery subtract values referenced by dates?
can excel powerquery subtract values referenced by dates?  Can't seem to ask the right question on google.  I know I can write a macro to do this but I'm looking for another easy way in excel.
for example, if I have a list of dates, account numbers, and value.
I'd like to say, for account "one", give me the difference in value between 5/16 and 5/15.
answer = +5
I am attempting to do this without making columns to pull in dates, then more columns to put in formulas.



date
acct
value




5/16
one
5


5/15
one
10


5/16
two
7


5/15
two
14




Yes, you can.
Group by acct, then do your aggregation depending on exactly what you want.
I show two different methods below, but you may have something else more specific in mind, so you can edit accordingly.
let

//change next line to reflect data type
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"acct", type text}, {"value", type number}}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"acct"}, {
        {"Value Difference", each List.Max([value]) - List.Min([value]), type number},
        {"Value 15 and 16", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t, each [date] = #date(2024,5,15))[value]{0} - 
            Table.SelectRows(t, each [date] =  #date(2024,5,16))[value]{0}, type number}
        
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

Results given your data

